# InfoPath Form Library Search not working after upgrade from SharePoint 2013 to 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

We upgraded from SharePoint 2013 to 2019, there is one site which has infopath forms library.

The search on the form library list it self seems to be working as I can search for older forms by form titles but any new forms that was submitted to the library after the upgrade are not searchable. When I try to search for a new form it will do like it's trying to search but nothing comes up in the results.

1. I ran a full crawl multiple times on the content source for this web app but it did not resolve my issue.
2. I also check in our old 2013 environment search schema and made sure the managed properties LinkFileName is set to Basic:10 is setup in our 2019 environment and ran a full crawl.
3. I also re index the list and ran a full crawl.

Edit:
When the infopath form is created the File name is generated by (concat(WorkZone, Positiontitle, now())

the search for workZone and position title works are they are actual fields in the list but it does not pickup the now() since its not a field.

Answer (score 0):

We just created 2 new fields and made the infopath form generate these fields based on values selected in the form. Those are hidden fields on the form so users don't see them.
The search now work for all new forms.